# What is the source of Shri Adi Shankaracharya saying "ईश्वरः नारायणशीलः" or "Ishwaraha Narayanasheelaha"?

Tags: advaita, vaishnavism, adi-shankaracharya, dvaita

In some religious discourse given by Shri Bannanje Govindacharya, I heard him say that Shri Adi Shankaracharya had said

> ईश्वरः नारायणशीलः
> Ishwaraha Narayanasheelaha

What is the source of it?

Comment: If possible, can you provide that saying in Devanagari Script?

Comment: @Pandya sure, will edit the question

Comment: @Pandya I have added it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is ईश्वरः सर्वज्ञः नारायणाख्यः ईशनशीलः ॥ १७ ॥ in the Bhagavadgita Bhashya by Shankara for the verse 15.17.

It means: The omniscient Ishwara, Lord, by the name Narayana, is Ishanashiila - the one who is of the nature of ruling, governing, the jivas and jagat. This expression Shankara has made more than once.

Comment: Thank you so much. More than once? Do you have references?

Comment: श्रीमद्भगवद्गीताभाष्यम्चतुर्थोऽध्यायःश्लोक ६ - भाष्यम्
………, तथा अव्ययात्मा अक्षीणज्ञानशक्तिस्वभावोऽपि सन् , तथा भूतानां ब्रह्मादिस्तम्बपर्यन्तानाम् ईश्वरः ईशनशीलोऽपि सन् , प्रकृतिं स्वां मम वैष्णवीं मायां त्रिगुणात्मिकाम् ,…

Comment: श्रीमद्भगवद्गीताभाष्यम्अष्टादशोऽध्यायःश्लोक ६१ - भाष्यम्
………ईश्वरः ईशनशीलः नारायणः सर्वभूतानां सर्वप्राणिनां हृद्देशे हृदयदेशे अर्जुन शुक्लान्तरात्मस्वभावः विशुद्धान्तःकरणः —………

Comment: Sir is this you? https://youtu.be/uW__QmgcOms